# Cant click edit button

Tags: support

I am a new user to SU. I was reading questions when i cam across a error in the text. I wanted to edit the text to correct it but the edit button is not clickable. Why so???

Comment: It might have been locked. Can you add the link?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you hover over the disabled "edit" button, it provides the specific reason for its state. Most likely, the post already had a pending suggested edit. If the post you wanted to edit was on meta, the link is disabled because suggested edits on meta can only be made to tag wikis. (Only users with 2,000 reputation and therefore the unilateral edit privilege can edit normal posts on meta.) The link is also disabled on the main site if the Suggested Edits review queue is at capacity, but I've never seen that happen on our site and it's definitely not happening now.